# Cartopy wmts KeyError issue : TileMatrixLimits

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, cartopy

Since a while, I am using the wmts function of cartopy but since last week this function does not works returning this error:

KeyError: 'TileMatrixLimits with tileMatrix "1" already exists'

The run code is coming from the cartopy web doc.

below the code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cartopy.crs as ccrs


def main():
    url = 'https://map1c.vis.earthdata.nasa.gov/wmts-geo/wmts.cgi'
    layer = 'VIIRS_CityLights_2012'

    fig = plt.figure()
    ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1, projection=ccrs.PlateCarree())
    ax.add_wmts(url, layer)
    ax.set_extent([-15, 25, 35, 60], crs=ccrs.PlateCarree())

    ax.set_title('Suomi NPP Earth at night April/October 2012')
    plt.show()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I do not understand what is wrong.

Thank for help.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please edit your question to include your code directly in the post, rather than linking to it. This will make it much more likely that your question gets answered.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve it commenting the lines 654 to 657 of *(your Python dir)/Lib/site-packages/owslib/wmts.py* which check the existence of the indexes in the static function ***from_elements*** of the ***TileMatrixSetLink*** class

Like this:

```
for limits_element in link_element.findall(path):
tml = TileMatrixLimits(limits_element)
if tml.tilematrix:
    #if tml.tilematrix in tilematrixlimits:
    #    msg = ('TileMatrixLimits with tileMatrix "%s" '
    #           'already exists' % tml.tilematrix)
    #    raise KeyError(msg)
    tilematrixlimits[tml.tilematrix] = tml

links.append(TileMatrixSetLink(uri, tilematrixlimits))
```

For portability effects you can replace that function in your code before you use it

Like this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cartopy.crs as ccrs

### START REPLACEMENT ###

from owslib.wmts import TileMatrixSetLink, TileMatrixLimits, _TILE_MATRIX_SET_TAG, _TILE_MATRIX_SET_LIMITS_TAG, _TILE_MATRIX_LIMITS_TAG

def custom_from_elements(link_elements):
    links = []
    for link_element in link_elements:
        matrix_set_elements = link_element.findall(_TILE_MATRIX_SET_TAG)
        if len(matrix_set_elements) == 0:
            raise ValueError('Missing TileMatrixSet in %s' % link_element)
        elif len(matrix_set_elements) > 1:
            set_limits_elements = link_element.findall(
                _TILE_MATRIX_SET_LIMITS_TAG)
            if set_limits_elements:
                raise ValueError('Multiple instances of TileMatrixSet'
                                  ' plus TileMatrixSetLimits in %s' %
                                  link_element)
            for matrix_set_element in matrix_set_elements:
                uri = matrix_set_element.text.strip()
                links.append(TileMatrixSetLink(uri))
        else:
            uri = matrix_set_elements[0].text.strip()

            tilematrixlimits = {}
            path = '%s/%s' % (_TILE_MATRIX_SET_LIMITS_TAG,
                              _TILE_MATRIX_LIMITS_TAG)
            for limits_element in link_element.findall(path):
                tml = TileMatrixLimits(limits_element)
                if tml.tilematrix:
                    tilematrixlimits[tml.tilematrix] = tml

            links.append(TileMatrixSetLink(uri, tilematrixlimits))
    return links

TileMatrixSetLink.from_elements = custom_from_elements

### END REPLACEMENT ###

def main():
    url = 'https://map1c.vis.earthdata.nasa.gov/wmts-geo/wmts.cgi'
    layer = 'VIIRS_CityLights_2012'

    fig = plt.figure()
    ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1, projection=ccrs.PlateCarree())
    ax.add_wmts(url, layer)
    ax.set_extent([-15, 25, 35, 60], crs=ccrs.PlateCarree())

    ax.set_title('Suomi NPP Earth at night April/October 2012')
    plt.show()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```